# Curl request C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, curl, post

I have an API Curl request, that returns a link:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' \
  -d '{
  "prompt": "A cute baby sea otter",
  "n": 2,
  "size": "1024x1024"
}'
```

How can I request the link through Curl in my C# script in Unity Engine? Thanks!

This is what I have so far:

```
void Start () {
     StartCoroutine ("FillAndSend");
        }

public IEnumerator FillAndSend() {
 #Curl request here
}
```

Comment: Use `UnityWebRequest` to make HTTP requests instead of using cURL: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dai stated out, you can use UnityWebRequest for this. You have few options to send it with. This is one way of doing it;

```cs
private const string YourApiKey = "3152-6969-1337";

void Start()
{
    var json = "{\"prompt\": \"A cute baby sea otter\",\"n\": 2,\"size\": \"1024x1024\"}";
    StartCoroutine(FillAndSend(json));
}

public IEnumerator FillAndSend(string json)
{
    using (var request = new UnityWebRequest("https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations", "POST"))
    {
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {YourApiKey}");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", " text/plain");

        request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer(); // You can also download directly PNG or other stuff easily. Check here for more information: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-CreatingDownloadHandlers.html

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError) // Depending on your Unity version, it will tell that these are obsolote. You can try this: request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success
        {
            Debug.LogError(request.error);
            yield break;
        }

        Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
        var response = request.downloadHandler.data; // Or you can directly get the raw binary data, if you need.
    }
}
```

You can also use `UnityWebRequest.Post(string uri, string postData)` method, or you can use `WWWForm` class to post with form, instead of JSON etc.

You can also create a model class for your data, then put `prompt`, `n`, and `size` properties in it. Afterwards, you can convert it to JSON with `JsonUtility.ToJson(dalleRequest)`. Or if you want, you can take those values as parameters for the method, then create the string while sending the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear explanation and help! it worked perfectly

Btw, you also need to import the following:

using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;